# Issues after macOS Sierra upgrade

Tags: macos

I recently updated to macOS Sierra on my MacBook Air. I have started noticing that desktop applications will startup automatically.

I have noticed this with Facetime and Slack. Whenever I access Facebook via Google Chrome, Facetime tends to open up and when I access Slack in the browser, the Slack desktop application starts up.

I have checked that I have not set any shortcut keys and it keeps happening frequently. Has anyone else noticed this issue? What can I do to stop it?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you do not have any OS updates left: [Upgrade OS X operating system](https://www.clihelp.org/MO00071/upgrade-os-x-operating-system)

Be sure your Google Chrome is up-to-date and check Settings -> Extensions

Let me know